# question on dynamic, SynchronousUpdating, inside Manipulate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to see if I can make my own simulation loop inside Manipulate as I am not happy with either the Trigger control or using Tasks (both have problems and limitations for what I'd like to do).

So, I was trying to see if I can make my own control loop, this way I have better control of things, where by clicking on a 'run' button, simulation loop will start until a 'stop' button is clicked.

A basic problem is that Manipulate times out after 5 seconds even though I am using `SynchronousUpdating -> False`. i.e. when I click the 'run' button, I start a loop (with some `Pause[]` in it of course), and will then update something in the loop. This works fine, but after 5 seconds, the loop stops on its own, since Manipulate decided to time out.

I might be misunderstanding something basic here. I show below simple example:

```
Manipulate[
Dynamic[Refresh[Text@x,TrackedSymbols->{x}]],

{{x,0},ControlType->None},
{{running,True},ControlType->None},

Button[Text["play"],
  {
   running=True,
   While[running,
     x+=1;
     FinishDynamic[];
     Pause[0.1]
   ]
  }],

Button[Text["stop"],
    running=False
  ],

TrackedSymbols->{None},
SynchronousUpdating->False,
SynchronousInitialization->False
]
```

When running the above, it always stops around count 58 or so, which is about 5 seconds, the time-out value for Manipulate

[image]

Outside Manipulate, it works ok as expected:

```
x = 0;
Dynamic[Refresh[x, UpdateInterval -> 0.001]]

Do[
 (
  x += 1;
  FinishDynamic[];
  Print[x];
  Pause[0.01]
  ), {i, 0, 200}
 ]
```

I can make the count above as large as I want, no problem.

So, it seems a configuration option for Manipulate, but I am now not able to find now which option it is I need to use for this to work.

Thanks

**Update**

Using the Method->"Queued" as given below by Simon, now the loop works. But there are problems with this method: I can not use Mathematica while the Button is running, even with large Pauses in the loop, as it blocks the whole front end. It behaves as if the button is pressed all the time. So, this idea is out of question to use. Well, it was something to try.

btw, this is a good time to mention this, I found that using cell of type 'code' instead of the default 'input' causes many crashes in the kernel. Just tried cell type 'code' and after few clicks on the button, kernel crashed:

[image]

So I no longer use cells of type 'code'.

Back to the drawing board.

**Update 2: 8/29/11, 6 PM**

Using Mathematica 8.0.1, on windows 7, SP1, intel pc, here is the code that crashes it when using "code" cell

```
Manipulate[
Dynamic[Refresh[Text@x,TrackedSymbols->{x},UpdateInterval->0.005]],

{{x,0},ControlType->None},
{{running,True},ControlType->None},

Button[Text["play"],
  {
   running=True,
   While[running,
     x+=1;
     FinishDynamic[];
   ]
  },Method->"Queued"],

Button[Text["stop"],
    running=False
  ],

TrackedSymbols->{None},
SynchronousUpdating->False,
SynchronousInitialization->False
]
```

May be someone can try the above? Had to click on start/stop few times to get it to crash.

I can reproduce this.

[image]

Update 9/2/11

on new answer: It looks Simon version (second one below) seems faster on my PC, Mathematica 8.0.1. I started both at the same time, and the Simon version seems to run faster (counter runs faster).

screen shot:

[image]

Comment: FYI, I have used the "code" style extensively on various versions of Mathematica since V6, both on Windows and Mac, and I have never seen a crash attributable to the use of that style.  I have run all of the code in this question from "code" style cells with no ill results (MMA 7.01 & 8.01, Windows, 64 bit).  On the other hand: shortly after the first time I installed MMA V8.00, the application fonts got corrupted somehow and the front-end would crash frequently just typing certain characters into *any* cell.  I ended up having to re-install Mathematica to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure why a "Code" styled cell should give you problems. Apart from the margins, background and default `InitializationCell->True` option, it should be the same as an "Input" cell. (@WReach - I didn't see your msg. I should have refreshed my browser before posting...)

Comment: Nasser: Is there a reason you can't move the incrementer outside of the button? e.g. `Manipulate[
 Dynamic[If[running, x++]; Refresh[Text@x, TrackedSymbols -> {x}]],
 {{x, 0}, None},
 {{running, True}, None},
 Button[Text["play"], running = True],
 Button[Text["stop"], running = False],
 TrackedSymbols -> {}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]` Then you don't even need the `SynchronousUpdating->False` option or some of the other stuff...

Comment: on "code" cell. I noticed it crashes more frequent when using "code" code when doing things involving UI (event handler, and mouse dragging, and the above example). I did not report it to WRI, may be I should do that. I just tried the above again, from fresh start of Mathematica, and after few key hits on the buttons, it crashed again, please see update 2.

Comment: @Simon, good idea, will try it. I was worried about not putting a pause in the loop, but it seems not to affect other mathematica notebook session when this is running in a loop like the above. WIll try your idea in my other larger demo I am writing to see how it will work. Thanks again!

Comment: Nasser: I ran the code (from a "Code" cell) you said crashed your notebook. Pressed start and stop lots of time, rerun the code, ad nauseam. It was fine (Mma 8.0.1 & Ubuntu 11.04). Maybe WReach is right, try a reinstall - that's always the recommended procedure on a windows box. Btw: Did Mma really crash or did Windows just saying it wasn't responding because of the button behaviour?

Comment: @Simon, thanks for trying. Mathematica did crash. The program stopped responding. The above message from windows saying the program stopped. This message comes up whenever Mathematica crahses. This might be a windows only issue, since you tried it on Linux.

Comment: I tried the code that crashes your MMA on a very similar software configuration to yours -- the difference being that I am on Windows 7 RTM instead of Windows 7 SP1.  I was unable to reproduce the crash, try as I might.  Are you saying that if you run this code from a normal Input cell, it does not crash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it's actually the `Button` that is timing out, not the `Manipulate`.

To quote the `Options > Method` section of the [Button docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html),

> By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link, which
>   times out after 5 seconds:

Set the option `Method -> "Queued"` for the button and everything works as expected.

Comment: @thanks Simon. +1, accepted. This is the option I missed! But at the end, I found I can't use this method to do what I want. Please see update.

Comment: +1. I had the same problem once about a year ago, and boy was it hard to figure out the reason (it was a rather complex UI).

Answer (score 1):

You might get better results if you let `Manipulate` control the "looping":

```
Manipulate[
  If[running, x++, x]
, {{x, 0}, ControlType -> None}
, {{running, True}, ControlType -> None}
, Button["play", running = True]
, Button["stop", running = False]
]
```

I presume that `Manipulate` is being used here to support further controls within the real application.  If not, then `DynamicModule` would be sufficient.

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, running = True}
, Column[
    { Button["play", running = True]
    , Button["stop", running = False]
    , Dynamic[If[running, x++, x]]
    }
  ]
]
```

The following example animates a moving disk using this technique:

```
DynamicModule[{t = 0, running = True}
, Column[
    { Button["play", running = True]
    , Button["stop", running = False]
    , Dynamic[
        If[running, t++, t] /.
          t_ :> Graphics[Disk[{Cos[t/10], Sin[t/10]}]
                       , PlotRange -> {{-3,3},{-3,3}}
                       , Axes -> True
                       ]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems on my PC at least, the answer given in the comment above by Simon runs a little faster, and the cell-side-bar do not show as 'busy' all the time? please see update

Comment: Fair enough.  Does the `DynamicModule` version crash your Mathematica?

Comment: your version of DynamicModule above did NOT crash my Mathematica ! That is good. I used cell of type 'code' as before, and kept try to get it to crash and it did not. I need to send a bug report to WRI of the above crash which happens when the cell is code as shown above.